# Unwanted repeat in method (with user input)

Tags: c#, methods, output

I have a fairly specific question on this otherwise functional piece of code. The problem is that whenever I run it, there is always a blank spot after the value, so the user has to enter their input twice. So the output would say...
[pic related](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgR7J.png)

```
    public string GetPayType()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter 1 if your pay type is a weekly hourly wage and 2 if your pay type is a monthly salary:");
        if (Console.ReadLine() == "1")
        {
            payType = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            return payType;
        }
        else if (Console.ReadLine() == "2") 
        {
            payType = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            return payType;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error! You may only enter a 1 or a 2!");
        }
        return payType;
    }
```

Comment: Side note: If you want the user to enter either 1 or 2, why return a string? Seems to me like you should probably use a `nullable<int>` or even `nullable<bool>` if you only ever expect to have two options. Also, why returning from the method if the user entered the wrong value instead of dealing with it inside the method? (in which case you don't need to return a nullable value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing the line below again after comparing the first input, you are basically  prompting for another input to return.

```
payType = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
return payType;
```

Try:

```
public string GetPayType()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter 1 if your pay type is a weekly hourly wage and 2 if your pay type is a monthly salary:");
        payType = Console.Readline();
        if (payType == "1" || payType == "2")
        {
            return payType;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error! You may only enter a 1 or a 2!");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

You might as well want to add a loop for the user if they entered an invalid input, I'll leave that to you for your own research.

Comment: Thank you! Everything seems to be working now.